# Загрузка изображений на хост и хранения пути в бд

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть форма заргузки картинки по url , идея в том чтоб сначало загрузить картинку на сервер и потом уже адрес прописать в бд.
Проблема 1:
Данный скрипт php загружает на сервер картинку по url , но сколько я б не загружал картинок оны заменяют друг друга , думаю проблема в том что у них одинаковое названия, не знаю как сделать чтоб названия генерировались.
Проблема 2:
Не знаю как после загрузки мне сохранить путь картинок в бд!

```js
<?php

$link = $_POST['link'];
$file = file_get_contents($link);
file_put_contents("site.jpg", $file);
 ?>
```

```html
<form action="reg.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="link" >
<button type="submit">Загрузить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно давать названия файлам по времени

```
$img_id=microtime(true);
file_put_contents($img_id.".jpg", $file);
```

А в БД хранить $img_id, с цифровыми данными обычно база летает шустрее и занимается меньше места. Зачем хранить пути в БД не совсем ясно - можно подставлять их при выборке из базы.

При большом объеме данных я бы организовал MySql таблицу следующим образом:

```
`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
`filetype` ENUM('jpg','png'),
`path` ENUM('cat','dog')

 вывод данных path/id.filetype
```

Comment: file_put_contents(time().".jpg", $file);
Но если я загружаю несколько картинок сразу то возникает проблема!

Comment: @DarkAdmiral ну добавляй к $img_id например порядковый номер картинки в цикле

Comment: @DarkAdmiral да я и сомневаюсь что у тебя каждая картинка будет быстрее отрабатываться чем microtime(true) меняется

Comment: Подскажи ищо как мне , пусть например /img/jpg поставить

Comment: @DarkAdmiral чаго??

Comment: Как мне изменить путь сохранения, например /img/my.jpg

Comment: @DarkAdmiral сейчас добавлю в ответ кой чаго